# How to create TFS reports to span multiple projects

Tags: tfs

We have a very standard / simple instance of TFS installed in our development environment.

I can see how to provide web access to a manager for a single project, e.g /tfs/fooProject, but I would really like to setup a worklist or add titles / homepage to the entire TFS instance.

This would be helpful as we host multiple projects, each with a couple of outstanding issues, and I would like it if a manger could go to a website and see a snapshot of all our applications on the one page.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Do you use multiple Team Project Collections?

Comment: Nope. A single project collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog post: http://blog.nwcadence.com/working-within-a-single-team-project-with-team-foundation-server-2012/

The basic idea is that you model levels of your organization using area paths. This will allow you to scope your Web Access view to the appropriate level.

Note that this is made considerable simpler in VS 2013 with the introduction of the Agile Portfolio Management Tools (http://blog.nwcadence.com/video-new-with-visual-studio-2013-manage-project-portfolios-to-understand-the-scope-of-work/)